# Okta Inbound SAML configuration broken, now unable to login to Admin Console

Tags: authentication, saml, okta

I am currently trying to setup Okta(Preview/Developer version) to federate logins to another IdP(say Google for instance).  To get this working, I was in the process of setting up Inbound SAML configuration.  However now am not even able to login to the Admin Panel for me to fix the configuration problems.  Based on the "SAML Guidance" document in Okta Documentation, I would assume there would be a Backdoor Login URL(non-SAML) which should just accept my Okta Developer Credentials and take me to Admin Panel.  Could not find one.  So am pretty much stuck now :(

Any help on how to get thru this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

There is a backdoor to every Okta org:

https://{{org}}.okta.com/login/default